# Override user pages with a view

Tags: views, users

Is it possible to override a user page with a view? I would like to override the user page to show all the nodes created by that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this!

In Views under relationship, select *Content: Author*

Then in under Contextual Filters select *Content Author UID*
Use the following settings for Content Author UID:

- Relationship: Nodes
- WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE: Provide
- Default Value / User ID from URL WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS AVAILABLE
  OR A DEFAULT IS PROVIDED: Specify Validation Criteria / Validator:
  User / Allow both numeric UIDs and string usernames

Then simply create a block and display it on the user page (Go to block settings and set the path to `users/*`

I hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

Views is not the right tool to use here, as views is for listing of content.

What you probably want is to use panels to take over the user page and display anything, like a view in it.

Comment: Might be better to use standard blocks than get Panels involved, it's a lot of bloat for such a simple thing

Comment: The OP is about a page listing all the nodes created by the user, which is content. It's not true that the Views module is for listing just content; it can create a list of users, and even a list of modules.

Comment: Well sure views is for listing things, but most users understand it much easier if you don't abstract that too much.

Comment: Whether panels is a lot of bloat is definitive not clear as it is an intelligent system in contrast to block rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the answer but try this module
http://drupal.org/sandbox/AshishThakur/1511158

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to replace the content of user page with views page (Tested)

```
function MODULE_menu_alter(&$items){
  $views_router = menu_get_item('path/to/my/views');
  if( $views_router ){
    $items['user/%user']['page callback'] = $views_router['page_callback'];
    $items['user/%user']['page arguments'] = $views_router['page_arguments'];
    $items['user/%user']['access callback'] = $views_router['access_callback'];
    $items['user/%user']['access arguments'] = unserialize($views_router['access_arguments']);
  }
}
```

Flush the cache and check the views accessibility settings.

Visit the user page for effective results.